# How can i pass array values in different pages in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I try to passing code {array} from one page to another,

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import SimpleStorage from "react-simple-storage";
import  ViewUsers from './ViewUsers';


export class AddUser extends Component{   

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newItem:" ",
      list: []
    };
  }

  updateInput(key, value) {
    // update react state
    this.setState({ [key]: value });
  }

  updatename(key,value){
    this.setState({[key]:value});
  }

   updatelname(key,value){
    this.setState({[key]:value});
  }
   updateage(key,value){
    this.setState({[key]:value});
  }

  addItem() {
    // create a new item with unique id
    const newItem = {
      id: 1 + Math.random(),
      value:this.state.newItem.slice(),
      fname:this.state.fname,
      lname:this.state.lname,
      age:this.state.age
    };

    const list = [...this.state.list];

    // add the new item to the list
    list.push(newItem);

    this.setState({
      list,
      newItem: " "
    });
    console.log(this.state.list);

}

  render() {
    let list=this.state.list
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <SimpleStorage parent={this} />
              <br/>

          Add Information:
          <br />
        <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">ID:</label>
        <input name="idIn" type="text" value={this.state.newItem} onChange={e => this.updateInput("newItem", e.target.value)} />
        <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
        <input name="fNameIn" value={this.state.fname} onChange={e => this.updatename("fname", e.target.value)}/>

        <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lNameIn" value={this.state.lname} onChange={e => this.updatelname("lname", e.target.value)}/>

        <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Age:</label>
        <input name="ageIn" value={this.state.age} onChange={e => this.updateage("age", e.target.value)} />
        <br/>
        <br/>

          <button
            onClick={() => this.addItem()}
            disabled={!this.state.newItem.length || !this.state.fname || 
              !this.state.lname || !this.state.age }
          >
            &#43; Add
          </button>
          <br /> <br />
          <div>
            <ViewUsers>
          {list.map(lis => 
            <div>{lis.id} </div> 
            )}
            </ViewUsers>

        </div>

          </div>
)}
}
```

This my GUI:

[image]

And this is a localstorage of my list :

[image]

now i need to show these information in another page 
that name as : ViewUsers.

So how can i do that ?
map doesn't work with me,

Also i try this code, but it give me an information about array not the real values:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I use this code in ViewUsers:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ViewUsers extends Component{

constructor(props) {

    super(props);

};
render(){
    return(
<ul>
 {this.props.list.map(item => (
   <li key={item}>{item}</li>
  ))}
</ul>


);

}
}
export default ViewUsers;
```

and i get this error:

[image]

and when i use:

```
props.list
```

instead of `this.props.list` 
i get error which say: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of your code,let me know if it helps.

**Add User Screen**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import SimpleStorage from "react-simple-storage";
import ViewUsers from './ViewUsers';


export class AddUser extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            newItem: " ",
            list: []
        };
    }

    updateInput(key, value) {
        // update react state
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    updatename(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    updatelname(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }
    updateage(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    addItem() {
        // create a new item with unique id
        const newItem = {
            id: 1 + Math.random(),
            value: this.state.newItem.slice(),
            fname: this.state.fname,
            lname: this.state.lname,
            age: this.state.age
        };

        const list = [...this.state.list];

        // add the new item to the list
        list.push(newItem);

        this.setState({
            list,
            newItem: " "
        });
        console.log(this.state.list);

    }

    render() {
        let list = this.state.list
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <SimpleStorage parent={this} />
                <br />
                Add Information:
                <br />
                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">ID:</label>
                <input name="idIn" type="text" value={this.state.newItem} onChange={e => this.updateInput("newItem", e.target.value)} />
                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
                <input name="fNameIn" value={this.state.fname} onChange={e => this.updatename("fname", e.target.value)} />

                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                <input name="lNameIn" value={this.state.lname} onChange={e => this.updatelname("lname", e.target.value)} />

                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <input name="ageIn" value={this.state.age} onChange={e => this.updateage("age", e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <button
                    onClick={() => this.addItem()}
                    disabled={!this.state.newItem.length || !this.state.fname ||
                        !this.state.lname || !this.state.age}
                >
                    &#43; Add
                </button>
                <br /> <br />
                <div>
                    <ViewUsers list={this.state.list}>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**View User Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ViewUsers extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            list: (this.props.list !== null && this.props.list !== undefined && this.props.list !== '' && Array.isArray(this.props.list)) ? this.props.list : []
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.list.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <table key={`list-item-${item.id}`}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ID</td>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>{item.fname} {item.lname}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Age</td>
                                <td>{item.age}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Value</td>
                                <td>{item.value}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );

    }
}
export default ViewUsers;
```

Comment: thank you very much, i use your code but the problem is it does not show any thing in viewUsers, when i try to use this: `console.log(props.list);` it give me undefined.

Comment: I have updated ViewUser component, please try with updated code. @norah

Comment: I try this also does not show any thing. And when i use this : `console.log(this.state.list);` it give me an empty array.

Comment: May be your list is not updated in add user screen, check that first

Comment: Sorry to bother you, the array appears in add user screen after refresh the browser, but  the strange thing to me is when  `console.log(this.state.list);`  which in viewUser it work twice in add user screen and view user screen even when i am just add it in view user !

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, what you want to achieve is to pass the list as "props" to the new component, in this case your ViewUsers component. Try:

```
<ViewUsers list={this.state.list} />
```

and then inside your ViewUsers component, you can get this list either as `this.props.list` or `props.list`, depending on whether it is a class component or a functional component. Then you can do the mapping and returning a div for the values.

A refresher on props might be helpful: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: thank you for your response, yes this is my problem and actually i tried these solutions but still there is a problem, so i updated the question  if you can check it  again.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a simple answer, this is an AddUsers file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import SimpleStorage from "react-simple-storage";
import  ViewUsers from './ViewDoctors';


 class AddUsers extends Component{   

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            newItem: " ",
            list: []
        };
    }

    updateInput(key, value) {
        // update react state
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    updatename(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    updatelname(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }
    updateage(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
    }

    addItem() {
        // create a new item with unique id
        const newItem = {
            id: this.state.id,
            fname: this.state.fname,
            lname: this.state.lname,
            age:   this.state.age
        };

        const list = [...this.state.list];

        // add the new item to the list
        list.push(newItem);

        this.setState({
            list,
            newItem: " "
        });
        console.log(this.state.list);

    }

    render() {
        //let list = this.state.list
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <SimpleStorage parent={this} />
                <br />
                Add Information:
                <br />
                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">ID:</label>
                <br />
                <input name="idIn" type="text" value={this.state.id || ""} onChange={e => this.updateInput("id", e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input name="fNameIn" value={this.state.fname || ""} onChange={e => this.updatename("fname", e.target.value)} />
                <br />

                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input name="lNameIn" value={this.state.lname || ""} onChange={e => this.updatelname("lname", e.target.value)} />
                <br />

                <label className="col-lg-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <br />
                <input name="ageIn" value={this.state.age || ""} onChange={e => this.updateage("age", e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <button
                    onClick={() => this.addItem()}
                    disabled={!this.state.id || !this.state.fname ||
                        !this.state.lname || !this.state.age}
                >
                   Add
                </button>
                <br /> <br />
                <div>
                    <ViewUsers list={this.state.list}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default AddUsers;
```

while this is a ViewUser file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ViewUsers extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            list: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_list')) 

        }


      //  console.log(this.state.list);
 };

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                {this.state.list.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={`list-item-${item.id}`}>

                                <p>ID {item.id}</p>

                                <p>Name {item.name}</p>

                                <p>Age {item.age}</p>  

                        </div>
                        );})}
                        </div>

                )}


}
export default ViewUsers;
```

And it works but the list must be not empty.

**Note:** in get item of viewusers file i write _list instead of list just because it is appear like this in my local-storage in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, because the child component receives the initial state of the list and there is no logic in the child component that it should rerender upon state change in parent... so use lifecycle methods in the child component to say that it should that it should rerender whenever there is state change in parent

Comment: i don't know too much about react but if you see the update answer, it works.. just i use  `this.state = {
            list: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_list'))  }` in ViewUsers. i didn't use it before ! and thank you..

Comment: I dont think think that's a good way to do that... it is better you use componentDidUpdate method or hooks like useEffect

Comment: yeah I see. thank you i appreciate it. I already try to use it now but, i will keep this post because it may helps someone in some part.